# How to hide Image on web pages using Angular 5

Tags: angular

Here i am input image using of ng2-file-input, Image is input successfully but image showing on web page so when i upload image i don't want image showing in web  page wan to hide image because it uploaded back-end.Below i shared my HTML code.
If you have any query please ask me in comments i will clarify.Thank you in advance.

```
<ng2-file-input class="Browse"  (onAction)="onAction($event)" [multiple]="false" [hidden]="Key"  [extensions]="['doc','pdf','txt','jpg','png']"></ng2-file-input>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wulkq.png)

Comment: can you please share your code on stackbiz

Comment: A screenshot would be useful as well

Comment: From github I've seen that there is a `  showPreviews:true; ` option in the forRoot import of the module, if you change that to false probably you'll get what you want. May I ask you.. ¿ Have you researched/tried something before coming here ?

Comment: Ng2FileInputModule.forRoot(
      {
         dropText:"Drop file here";
         browseText:"Browse";
         removeText:"Remove";
         invalidFileText:"You have picked an invalid or disallowed file."
         invalidFileTimeout:8000;
         removable:true;
         multiple:false;
         showPreviews:true;
         extensions:['jpg'];
      }
    ),

Comment: @Osakr you will see screen shot below code.

Comment: @harkeshkumar I already did this.Thank you

Comment: @shubham can you share some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your code please check in your
`showPreviews:true;` change to false and stop showing preview of uploading images

```
Ng2FileInputModule.forRoot(
          {
             dropText:"Drop file here";
             browseText:"Browse";
             removeText:"Remove";
             invalidFileText:"You have picked an invalid or disallowed file."
             invalidFileTimeout:8000;
             removable:true;
             multiple:false;
             showPreviews:true;
             extensions:['jpg'];
          }
        ),
```

Or you try this
`[showPreviews]:false` add in below line

```
<ng2-file-input class="Browse"  (onAction)="onAction($event)" [multiple]="false" [hidden]="Key" [showPreviews]:false  [extensions]="['doc','pdf','txt','jpg','png']"></ng2-file-input>
```

Comment: Great it's working this is exactly i want...Thank you.

Comment: yes i voted. if i want to show image in browser or some popup then how can i show

Comment: Like some other file also like txt or PDF

Comment: you can start a consverstion to chat more